# Test if SSL certificate of remote server is accepted by my application

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I am the maintainer (not programmer) of a Tomcat application which connects to a remote web server via HTTPS. I fear that the remote certificate is either not trusted or has an unknown algorithm. How can I check this?

I cannot find any traces in Tomcat logs (catalina, ...), and I have no idea how I could use keytool with it.

Is there a way I can do without writing a Java program, or is there a simple code snippet I can test with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the following link you could find something really close to what you need:

https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029

Regards

Comment: This was a massive step forward!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ssl-debug on the java process: 
[Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Basically add this to the tomcat CATALINA_OPTS

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```